# Parse Soap Response with PHP simplexml_load_file or the SoapClient()

Tags: php, xml, soap, simplexml

Someone maybe any idea how I can parse the elements of BookingResponse of the Soap Response with PHP. I am totally stuck since hours. Nothing worked. I tried the SoapClient() and simplexml_load_file() and xpath. Nothing lead to something usable. :(

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <BatchDisplayBookingResponse xmlns="http://www.server.com/url">
         <BatchDisplayBookingResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <BookingResponse>
               <SessionId>theSessionId</SessionId>
               <Version i:nil="true"/>
               <Currency>EUR</Currency>
               <Success>true</Success>
               <Code>100</Code>
               <Messages>
                  <Text>This is a text 1</Text>
                  <Text>This is a text 1</Text>
               </Messages>
            </BookingResponse>
         </BatchDisplayBookingResult>
      </BatchDisplayBookingResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Thanks a lot
TA

Comment: and what was the problem?

Comment: I could just manage it yet unfortunately. I assume it is somehow connected to the additionally namespaces in the SOAP response. Do you know a good way to get maybe the Currency or the Text elements? thx

Comment: Show your `SoapClient` code that is not working

Comment: The problem is, that I only have the response of the SOAP interface but not direct access to the service itself. That's why I think, the SOAP client will not work cause it is function and service orientated. Maybe the XML approach might the better one? Any idea how to parse this snippet via simplexml_load_file() and xpath()? thx

Comment: Explain your use case in more detail. If you cannot use the soap server directly, you cannot use the SoapClient class because that needs a server. But IF you have access, you should use it. Otherwise demand not to get XML. ;)

Comment: Makes sense, Sven. :) I need to sync the Soap Response with a local database. But I think, you are right, it's a kind of deadlock here.

I thought, it might possible to parse an "offline" Soap Response to setup the whole sync process (replicate objects into the tables), cause the Soap Server has a really lousy response so I wanted to store the soap response in a database for faster usage  in a croned enviroment.